# Redis and mysql database

Tags: mysql, redis

I'm currently using Redis in my webProject (predis).
I'm using Redis as Cache server and when I get empty results from redis I would like to look into my MySQL database and store that result into redis.

Also, how would I dump the redis into MySQL to make sure MySQL has the up-to-date content? My plan is to dump redis into MySQL so if the redis is empty it will look in MySQL for the details.

How would I proceed to do this?
Should I do one or two?

After editing/inserting into Redis, do the same to MySQL

Redis -> dump to MySQL -> get from MySQL if empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you mean to say these things as things are not clear from your question.
You are using Redis as Cache server and when you get empty results from redis you are going to look into your MySQL database and store that result into redis.

Well if your web application is in Java you can try few things as:

1. create a Jedis Connection.
2. try to get the value from redis corresponding to that key.
3. if nothing is returned. You can query the same from your database.
4. Set the (key value) to redis.

Comment: Hello. Im currently working in PHP using redis (predis).

Comment: you can perform same thing with predis as well.

Comment: But should i dump redis to mysql or when editing /inserting redis do the same to an backup in mysql db?

Comment: no you should not dump redis to mysql.better to define in the config file that how often you want to save things to disk.

Comment: @user3134514 How do i do this ? and how do it acually saves to disk?

Comment: define a config file let it be as redis.config and in that you can define a save command as save time no-of-operation    here time refers to the minimum time after which the data will be written to disk and 2nd one(optional) is minimum number of operation that will write to disk. refer to this for more details  http://redis.io/commands/save